# Proving a theorem with Equality.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from "[Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf)" by Elliot Mendelson , page 96 , exercise 2.65(a). I have to prove the following theorem (we are working in a theory with equality):

> $\vdash (\forall x)(\mathscr B(x) \leftrightarrow (\exists y)(x = y \land \mathscr B(y)))$ if $y$ does not occur in $\mathscr B(x)$

I guess I have to show that $\vdash (\mathscr B(x) \leftrightarrow (\exists y)(x = y \land \mathscr B(y)))$ and $\vdash (\forall x)(\mathscr B(x) \leftrightarrow (\exists y)(x = y \land \mathscr B(y)))$ follows from that by **Gen**. So , I have to show that $\vdash (\mathscr B(x) \rightarrow (\exists y)(x = y \land \mathscr B(y)))$ and $\vdash (\mathscr B(x) \leftarrow (\exists y)(x = y \land \mathscr B(y)))$

For the first case:

1. $\mathscr B(x)$
2. $x = x$ [Proposition 2.23(a)]
3. $x = x \land \mathscr B(x)$ [conjunction introduction]
4. $(\exists y)(x = y \land \mathscr B(y)) $ [rule E4]
5. $\mathscr B(x) \vdash (\exists y)(x = y \land \mathscr B(y)) $
6. $\vdash \mathscr B(x) \to  (\exists y)(x = y \land \mathscr B(y)) $ [Deduction]

I am stuck on the second case. I cant really use the rule E4 on proving the second case . I also tried to work backwards to find an easier wf I can prove to prove the second case.But that just made the problem harder. **Can someone give me a hint?**

Just for comparison , I tried to prove exercise 2.65(b) , which only differs from a quantifier.I am not fully sure if my proof is correct or not , but I tried.

> $\vdash (\forall x)(\mathscr B(x) \leftrightarrow (\forall y)(x = y \land \mathscr B(y)))$ if $y$ does not occur in $\mathscr B(x)$

**Proof:**

1. $\mathscr B(x)$
2. $x=y \to (\mathscr B(x) \to \mathscr B(y))$ [axiom A7]
3. $\mathscr B(x) \to (x=y \to \mathscr B(y))$
4. $x=y \to \mathscr B(y)$
5. $(\forall y)(x=y \to \mathscr B(y))$
6. $\mathscr B(x) \vdash (\forall y)(x=y \to \mathscr B(y))$
7. $\vdash \mathscr B(x) \to (\forall y)(x=y \to \mathscr B(y))$ [deduction]
8. $(\forall y)(x=y \to \mathscr B(y))$
9. $x=x \to \mathscr B(x)$
10. $x=x$ [Proposition 2.23(a)]
11. $\mathscr B(x)$
12. $(\forall y)(x=y \to \mathscr B(y)) \vdash \mathscr B(x)$
13. $\vdash (\forall y)(x=y \to \mathscr B(y)) \to \mathscr B(x)$
14. $\vdash \mathscr B(x) \to (\forall y)(x=y \to \mathscr B(y) \land (\forall y)(x=y \to \mathscr B(y)) \to \mathscr B(x)$ [conjunction intorduction]
15. $\vdash \mathscr B(x) \leftrightarrow (\forall y)(x=y \to \mathscr B(y))$ [biconditional introduction]
16. $\vdash (\forall x)(\mathscr B(x) \leftrightarrow (\forall y)(x=y \to \mathscr B(y)))$ [Gen]

Comment: In the reverse direction you have to use existential elimination on $(\exists y)(x = y \land \mathscr B(y))$ to get $x = y \land \mathscr B(y)$. Then you need some rules regarding equality to conclude $\mathscr B(x)$.

Comment: @Lereau Can you show me where did you find "existential elimination" in mendelsons textbook?

Comment: I just saw that Mendelson defines $\exists x \mathscr B(x)$ as $\neg \forall x \neg \mathscr B(x)$ so it does require a bit more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy if you use rule C (existential specification). However,
the exercise is asking for a proof for any logic with equality. So, perhaps rule C is not included. So, you should transform your proof into one that does not use rule C, according with the method which Mendelson provides in page 83. Here is a proof of $\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)\vdash_{C}\mathscr{B}(x)$:

1. $\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)$ (premise)
2. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)$ (rule c)
3. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha$ (conjunction
   elimination)
4. $x=\alpha$ (M.P. 3,2)
5. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(\alpha)$
   (conjunction elimination)
6. $\mathscr{B}(\alpha)$ (M.P. 5,2)
7. $x=\alpha\rightarrow\alpha=x$ (property 2.23-b)
8. $\alpha=x$ (M.P. 7,4)
9. $\alpha=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)$ (axiom A7)
10. $\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)$ (M.P. 9,8)
11. $\mathscr{B}(x)$ (M.P. 10,6)

Now, we transform it into a proof of $\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)\vdash\mathscr{B}(x)$:

1. $\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right),x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\vdash\mathscr{B}(x)$
   (step 2 of the proof became a premise)
2. $\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)\vdash x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)$
   (by deduction theorem)
3. $\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)\vdash\forall z\left(x=z\wedge\mathscr{B}(z)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)$
   (by universal generalization)
4. $\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)\vdash\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)$
   (by exercise 2.32)
5. $\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)\vdash\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)$
   (tautological)
6. $\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)\vdash\mathscr{B}(x)$

I will go further, in order to make it more clear. We evoked the deduction
theorem to go from step 1 to step 2, in the transformation above.
Instead, the proof of the deduction theorem can show us how we can
get there, without using it. We use the following theorems of propositional
logic:

1. $p\rightarrow p$
2. $p\rightarrow\left(q\rightarrow p\right)$
3. $\left(p\rightarrow q\right)\rightarrow\left[\left[p\rightarrow\left(q\rightarrow r\right)\right]\rightarrow\left(p\rightarrow r\right)\right]$

After each step $i$ of the proof, we do the following: if the formula
$S_{i}$ of stem $i$ is a premise, an axiom or a theorem, then, we
introduce the formula $S_{i}\rightarrow\left(Q\rightarrow S_{i}\right)$
(theorem 2), where $Q$ is the premise we want to eliminate, and we
use modus ponens. Here, $Q$ is: $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)$.
If $S_{i}$ is $Q$, we replace it with $Q\rightarrow Q$ (theorem
1). If $S_{i}$ occurred from modus ponens, from formulas $S_{j}$
and $S_{j}\rightarrow S_{i}$, $j<i$, then we already have $Q\rightarrow S_{j}$
and $Q\rightarrow\left(S_{j}\rightarrow S_{i}\right)$. We replace
$S_{i}$ with $\left(Q\rightarrow S_{j}\right)\rightarrow\left[\left[Q\rightarrow\left(S_{j}\rightarrow S_{i}\right)\right]\rightarrow\left(Q\rightarrow S_{1}\right)\right]$
(theorem 3), and apply modus ponens twice. Finally, we have a proof
of $Q\rightarrow R$, where $R$ is the conclusion of our initial
proof. Here, $R$ is $\mathscr{B}(x)$:

1. $\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)$ (premise)
2. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)$ (th. 1)
3. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha$ (conjunction
   elimination)
4. $\left(x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha\right)\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha\right)\right]$
   (th. 2)
5. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha\right)$
   (M.P. 4,3)
6. $\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\right]\rightarrow\left(\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha\right)\right]\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha\right]\right)$
   (th. 3)
7. $\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha\right)\right]\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha\right]$
   (M.P. 6,2)
8. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha$ (M.P. 7,5)
9. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(\alpha)$
   (conjunction elimination)
10. $\left(x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\right)\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\right)\right]$
    (th. 2)
11. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\right)$
    (M.P. 10,9)
12. $\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\right]\rightarrow\left(\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\right)\right]\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\right]\right)$
    (th. 3)
13. $\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\right)\right]\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\right]$
    (M.P. 12,2)
14. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(\alpha)$
    (M.P. 13,11)
15. $x=\alpha\rightarrow\alpha=x$ (property 2.23-b)
16. $\left(x=\alpha\rightarrow\alpha=x\right)\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\rightarrow\alpha=x\right)\right]$
    (th. 2)
17. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\rightarrow\alpha=x\right)$ (M.P. 16,15)
18. $\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow x=\alpha\right]\rightarrow\left(\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\rightarrow\alpha=x\right)\right]\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\alpha=x\right]\right)$
    (th. 3)
19. $\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\rightarrow\alpha=x\right)\right]\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\alpha=x\right]$
    (M.P. 18,8)
20. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\alpha=x$ (M.P. 19,17)
21. $\alpha=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)$
    (axiom A7)
22. $\left[\alpha=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)\right]\rightarrow\left(x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left[\alpha=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)\right]\right)$
    (th. 2)
23. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left[\alpha=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)\right]$
    (M.P. 22,21)
24. $\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\alpha=x\right]\rightarrow\left(\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left[\alpha=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)\right]\right]\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)\right]\right)$
    (th. 3)
25. $\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left[\alpha=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)\right]\right]\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)\right]$
    (M.P. 24,20)
26. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)$ (M.P. 25,23)
27. $\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\right]\rightarrow\left(\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)\right]\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right]\right)$
    (th. 3)
28. $\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)\right]\rightarrow\left[x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right]$ (M.P. 27,14)
29. $x=\alpha\wedge\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)$ (M.P. 28,26)
30. $\forall z\left(x=z\wedge\mathscr{B}(z)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)$
    (Un. Gen. 29)
31. $\exists y\left(x=y\wedge\mathscr{B}(y)\right)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)$
    (property by exercise 2.32, on 30)
32. $\mathscr{B}(x)$ (M.P. 31,1)

Comment: I think you cant use the instance $\alpha=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)$ of axiom A7 directly.You have to first use  $y=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(y)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)$ of axiom A7 then by Gen  $(\forall y)(y=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(y)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right))$ and by rule A4 , $\alpha=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)$. Is this ok?

Comment: Sure you can. Since $x$ and $y$ are variables (see Mendelson, p. 95), $y=x\rightarrow\left(\mathscr{B}(y)\rightarrow\mathscr{B}(x)\right)$ is not, strictly speaking, an axiom, but an axiom schema (a formula with one or more free variables is not a statement. Axioms are statements). Any statement that occurs from substitution of the variables of an axiom schema with constants, is an axiom.

Comment: According to page 95 about the schema of (A7) , they said $x$ and $y$ has to be variables , not constants. So, to put constants there , you have to use Gen and rule A4 on the instance of axiom schema (A7). right?

Comment: No, you can put constants directly. An axiom system with an axiom schema, has actually an infinite number of axioms. The schema is a rule to construct these axioms, by substituting its variables with constants. So, the result of such a substitution, is an axiom of your system and thus, you can evoke it at any time, without any further justification.

Comment: I know that. But in the book, while mentioning (A7) as a axiom schema , they have put specific instruction about what counts as a instance of (A7) "_**where x and are any variables**, B(x,x) is any wf, and B(x,y) arises from 
.B(x,x) by replacing some, but not necessarily all, free occurrences x by y, 
with the proviso that y is free for x in B(x,x). Thus, B(x,y) may or may not 
contain free occurrences of x._" They did not say that x and y can be constants , but variables . But of course , as @Mauro said , we can make (A7) hold for terms too by using Gen and rule A4.

Comment: You are right that Mendelson does it the way you describe. But, in general, it is usual to get axioms from axiom schemas directly, without doing generalization - specification. So, to my knowledge, the above is correct. Any way, in order to follow Mendelson's practice, go ahead and add the steps that you are suggesting.

Comment: thanks for your clarification. Great answer :)

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

Use Rule C.

From premise $(∃y)(x=y ∧ B(y))$ we have $(x=b ∧ B(b))$ for some $b$.

Thus, using substitutivity of equality we have $B(x)$.

Thus, $(∃y)(x=y ∧ B(y)) \vdash_C B(x)$ and from Prop.2.10: $(∃y)(x=y ∧ B(y)) \vdash B(x)$.

Comment: I am not really sure how you used substitutivty of equality (especially because there is a constant instead of a variable). Can you show me that?

Comment: @Prithubiswas - obviously it works. You have to apply Gen to (A7) and then use (A4) to instantiate it using the term $b$. In a nutshell, the equality axioms hold for *terms*.

Answer (score 0):

I seems Mendelson defines $\exists x \, \mathscr B(x)$ as $\neg \forall x \, \neg \mathscr B(x)$ so let's use this definition in the proof.

1. $(\exists y)( x = y ~\land \mathscr B(y)) \vdash  \mathscr B(x)$
2. $\neg (\forall y ) \neg ( x = y ~\land \mathscr B(y)) \vdash \mathscr B(x)~~~~$ [ Definition of $\exists$ ]
3. $\neg \mathscr B(x) \vdash(\forall y ) \neg ( x = y ~\land \mathscr B(y))~~~~$ [Contraposition]
4. $\neg \mathscr B(x) \vdash \neg ( x = y ~\land \mathscr B(y))~~~~$
5. $ x = y ~\land \mathscr B(y) \vdash \mathscr B(x)~~~~$ [Contraposition]
6. $~\vdash x = y \rightarrow \mathscr B(y) \rightarrow \mathscr B(x)~~~~$ [A7 (page 95)]

---

The jump

$1.$ $(\exists y)( x = y ~\land \mathscr B(y)) \vdash  \mathscr B(x)$

$5.$ $ ~~~~~~~~~~x = y ~\land \mathscr B(y) \vdash \mathscr B(x)$

is a useful lemma in general.

Comment: How did you derive $(\exists y)( x = y ~\land \mathscr B(y)) \vdash  \mathscr B(x)$ ?

Comment: @Prithubiswas That is just the start of the proof. From $\vdash (\exists y)( x = y ~\land \mathscr B(y)) \rightarrow \mathscr B(x)$ you get $(\exists y)( x = y ~\land \mathscr B(y)) \vdash  \mathscr B(x)$.

Comment: But isnt it what we want to actually prove?

Comment: @Prithubiswas No, it's one step of the proof and the step is justified by the deduction theorem (proposition 1.9) on page 37.